# React Native - Is there any possible way to embed elements within the text of a text input?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input

I would like to allow the users to type raw text into an input, but also allow them to embed special kinds of content within the raw text.

For example:

[image]

My hope would be that the element would be handled by React Native as essentially just an extra big text character, so that it could be multi-selected, backspaced, etc.

If this is not supported by default in React Native, would it even be possible to implement this functionality on my own? Or is this type of feature not even supported on the native (Android/iOS) environments?

Comment: I would suggest you to explore draftjs ...

Comment: @TusharPandey - Thanks for the reply. Do you know if that's compatible with React Native?  From a quick gloss of the documentation, it seems that it was built for normal React.

Comment: yes. .... of course , my friend has created POC for that.